# Excel Nesting Issue

Tags: excel, nested

I have got a formula which returns an error informing the IFs are nesting too much. Is it possible to do it the other way in order to get the results I require?

Please see below example:

```html
<table>
  
<tr><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td><td>G</td><td>H</td><td>I</td><td>J</td></tr>      
<tr><td>SKU</td><td>Description</td><td>Height</td><td>Depth</td><td>Width</td><td>Box</td><td>Depth</td><td>Height</td><td>Width</td><td>Exceed by 5%?</td></tr>
  <tr><td>30200616</td><td>DORMA MIRRORED WALL CLOCK 44*44 CHAMP</td><td>460</td><td>70</td><td>450</td><td>"=IF(G2+H2+I2>=50%*1265,
IF(AND(G2<=BOXES!$B$2, H2<=BOXES!$C$2, I2<=BOXES!$D$2), BOXES!$A$2,
IF(AND(G2<=BOXES!$B$3, H2<=BOXES!$C$3, I2<=BOXES!$D$3), BOXES!$A$3,
IF(AND(G2<=BOXES!$B$4, H2<=BOXES!$C$4, I2<=BOXES!$D$4), BOXES!$A$4,
IF(AND(G2<=BOXES!$B$5, H2<=BOXES!$C$5, I2<=BOXES!$D$5), BOXES!$A$5,
IF(AND(G2<=BOXES!$B$6, H2<=BOXES!$C$6, I2<=BOXES!$D$6), BOXES!$A$6,  BOXES!$A$7))))),BOXES!$A$8)"</td><td>"=MIN(C2:E2)"</td><td>"=MAX(C2:E2)"</td><td>"=SMALL(C2:E2, 2)"</td><td>"=IF(G2+H2+I2>=50%*1265,
IF(AND(G2<=BOXES!$B$2, H2<=BOXES!$C$2, I2<=BOXES!$D$2), BOXES!$A$2,
IF(AND(G2<=BOXES!$B$7, H2<=BOXES!$C$7, I2<=BOXES!$D$7), BOXES!$A$7,
IF(AND(G2<=BOXES!$B$3, H2<=BOXES!$C$3, I2<=BOXES!$D$3), BOXES!$A$3,
IF(AND(G2<=BOXES!$B$8, H2<=BOXES!$C$8, I2<=BOXES!$D$8), BOXES!$A$8,
IF(AND(G2<=BOXES!$B$4, H2<=BOXES!$C$4, I2<=BOXES!$D$4), BOXES!$A$4,
IF(AND(G2<=BOXES!$B$9, H2<=BOXES!$C$9, I2<=BOXES!$D$9), BOXES!$A$9,
IF(AND(G2<=BOXES!$B$5, H2<=BOXES!$C$5, I2<=BOXES!$D$5), BOXES!$A$5,
IF(AND(G2<=BOXES!$B$10, H2<=BOXES!$C$10, I2<=BOXES!$D$10), BOXES!$A$10,
IF(AND(G2<=BOXES!$B$6, H2<=BOXES!$C$6, I2<=BOXES!$D$6), BOXES!$A$6,
IF(AND(G2<=BOXES!$B$11, H2<=BOXES!$C$11, I2<=BOXES!$D$11), BOXES!$A$11,
  BOXES!$A$12)))))))))),BOXES!$A$13)"</td></tr>
  </table>
```

J column should provide the information if the item is slightly exceeding the box size. If it does, it should return the info here.

The Bin Size tab below.

[image]

can you please instruct me whether it's possible to get that function going, avoid the nesting restriction?

Comment: Have you tried your luck with [match](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a) and -1 match type? Something similar to what you are trying to accomplish can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc750573.aspx) (ever so slightly outdated).

Comment: yes it is possible!

Comment: missed the first part of your if statement as it was buried in some other codding that is not part of an excel formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proof of Concept

[image: Proof of Concept]

The table you have is key to your answer I believe.  you will need to sort your table though to suit your needs as the following answer will return the first row of the table that meets all three categories.  As such you MIGHT want to sort your table by height or width.

```
=IF(G2+H2+I2>=1265/2,IFERROR(INDEX($O$3:$O$12,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($O$3:$O$12)/(($P$3:$P$12>=G2)*($Q$3:$Q$12>=H2)*($R$3:$R$12>=I2)),1)-ROW($O$3)+1),"BIG KITE"),"No Packaging - Too small")
```

That formula assumes your table is in the range of O2 to R14 with O2 being the header row.

The first if is required as your TOO SMALL check does not follow the logic of your table.  So we do the special case check, and decide if we are going into the table or saying its too small first.  If something is not found on the table, then it returns an error.  Therefore using the IFERROR we return the result of "BIG KITE".  Feel free to customize within the quotes.  The aggregate function then tries to find the first row that meets your size requirements which is why your table needs to be sorted the way showing in the picture.  if you do not, then an item that would fit in slightly exceeding box 1 will pick box 2 instead.